# Cards on a $4\times 13$ array

Tags: probability

One lays down a deck of $52$ cards face up on a $4 \times 13$ array .One tries to select $13$ cards one from each column with different denominations (not necessarily of different suites)

Find the probability that the selection is possible. Justify your answer
  I am getting $\frac{4^{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$.

Don't know wrong or right please help

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't explain how you got your answer.

Comment: When you said 52 cards in 4 x 13 array, Are you arranging it in certain way or does this choice belongs to us?????

Comment: I have 4 possible choices for every 13 denominations which is the numerator

Comment: The choice is random, at least from what I read.

Comment: The choice belongs to the person dealing the cards

Comment: That is a tiny number, around $10^{-4}$.  I suspect the probability is $1$.  Clearly if you only have $13$ cards and put them in columns of $1$ you can do so.  If you have $13\times 2$ cards and put them in columns of $2$ you can always do so.  Pick one card from each column where the two match.  Then pick one card at random, pick the match of the other one in its column and keep going.  You will never get trapped, though you may come to the end of a cycle and need to start again.  I can't prove it for $13 \times 4$

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: I think this is always possible, but I have no idea how to prove it.  I wrote a python script, using Knuth's dancing links algorithm to solve the problem, and 10,000 random trials were all successful.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right, it's 1.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is always possible, by Hall's Marriage Theorem.  The problem is a bipartite matching problem, with one set being the ranks, and the other set being the columns.  There is an edge between a given rank and a given column if and only if the column contains a card of that rank.  We seek a complete matching, that is, a set of edges such that each vertex is on exactly one of them.

Given a set $S$ of $r$ ranks, let $s$ be the number of columns that contain a card of at least one of the ranks in $S$. We cannot have $s < r$ for there are $4r$ cards of the given ranks, and only $4s < 4r$ cards in the columns of $S$.  By Hall's Marriage Theorem, there exists a complete matching, which proves the theorem.

So the probability is 1. I wonder what the expected number of solutions is?